# How can I apply multiple DoubleAnimation on TextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, animation

I have variables like this

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="AdvArea" Margin="10,0,0,0">
    <Canvas x:Name="Advertise" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="10,0,0,0" >
        <TextBlock Name="AdvMarquee" Text="Scroll Text For Advertise" Padding="10, 0, 10, 0"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

I finally applied Marquee with DoubleAnimation on TextBlock with this code.

```
private void UserControl_Loaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    doubleAnimation.From = -AdvMarquee.ActualHeight;
    doubleAnimation.To = 0;
    doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
    doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration( TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) );

    AdvMarquee.BeginAnimation( Canvas.TopProperty, doubleAnimation );

    // Dev Area
    List<String> Messages = new List<String>();

    Messages.Add( String.Format( "AdvMarquee : HasAnimatedProperties > " + AdvMarquee.HasAnimatedProperties ) );
    Messages.Add( String.Format( "doubleAnimation.From : " + doubleAnimation.From ) );
    Messages.Add( String.Format( "doubleAnimation.To : " + doubleAnimation.To ) );
    Messages.Add( String.Format( "doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior : " + doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior ) );
    Messages.Add( String.Format( "doubleAnimation.Duration : " + doubleAnimation.Duration ) );


    MessageBox.Show( String.Join("\n", Messages ) );
}
```

What I planned to do was Scroll text from outside of range to screen

and stop a moment for show

after that, scroll from screen to outside.

but I don't know how to apply another animation after exist animation finished.

**My Scenario**

1. Scroll down my text from outside of screen to screen
2. keep this text for a moment ( for example, 10 seconds )
3. scroll down again from screen to outside of screen.

**What I need to know**

1. Apply DoubleAnimation to TextBlock ( Done )
2. Apply Another DoubleAnimation when First DoubleAnimation Finished.

Any tip is okay so, give me your hands.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a storyboard, which is an object that allows multiple child animations. Use it to animate more than a single property at once and also to chain animations one after another. Start with the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/storyboards-overview).